# "Cannot Start Application" Error from IE when posting multipart/form data

Tags: windows, tomcat, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to resolve a problem that is happening on a couple of machines. 
I have a web application which is pure javascript (no plugins)

When the user is attempting to send one request to the server it generates an error dialog 
[image]

The request is to a Tomcat Server and is multipart/form-data.

The details are as follows

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34280 built by: FX452RTMGDR
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34280 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://iacts01:8080/iActs/notification/addAttachment.action

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://iacts01:8080/iActs/notification/addAttachment.action resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://iacts01:8080/iActs/notification/addAttachment.action did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/15/2016 1:34:29 PM] : Activation of http://iacts01:8080/iActs/notification/addAttachment.action has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/15/2016 1:34:29 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://iacts01:8080/iActs/notification/addAttachment.action did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I cannot work out what is causing this or how to fix it. 
All other calls to the server take place unhindered.
If I try with Chrome no issues occur. Unfortunately that is not a standard browser for the company and they cannot use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in getting this working.
I was posting back to ...../addAttachment.action. However it appears the user in question had a badly installed application that used the ".action" suffix and Internet Explorer attempted to fire up the application.
Most of my entries were for AJAX but because of the form needing to post a file, this was being submitted as a standard submit.

The solution was to change to post to a url with a suffix of ".html" instead, and the issue went away.